# What kind of index should I create to make "WHERE col1 LIKE '0000%' AND col2 = 'somevalue'" faster?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance, sql-like

I tried the following queries in order to search inside a quad tree using PostgreSQL's `LIKE` operator. In column `col3`, there are words like '0133002112300300320' inserted, which describes the quad tree's path.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(col1 CHARACTER(9) NOT NULL,
 col2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
 col3 CHARACTER VARYING(64),
 col4 INTEGER NOT NULL,
 col5 DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(col1,col2,col3));

-- Performs sequential search
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
FROM table1
WHERE col1='somevalue' AND col2=0 AND col3 LIKE '01330021123003003%';
```

The problem is that the PRIMARY KEY index I set doesn't work with `WHERE col1='somevalue' AND col2=0 AND col3 LIKE '01330021123003003%'`. It seems that I can't use `LIKE` operator with `AND` operator at the same time if you want to use the created index.

Are there any special indices I can create to make this `SELECT` faster?

Comment: Pattern matching anchored to the beginning (`col LIKE 'foo%'`) can use indexes if the database deems it beneficial.  How did you determine that it "doesn't work"?

Comment: I figured out using `EXPLAIN`. It's sure that `col LIKE 'foo%'` can use indices, but how about `col1 LIKE 'foo%' AND col2='baz'`? Can it still use indices?

Comment: How many rows are in the table? Show the EXPLAIN please.

Comment: There are 1033810 rows. `Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..48498.61 rows=1 width=89)
  Filter: (((col3)::text ~~ '01330021123003003%'::text) AND (col1 = 'somevalue'::bpchar) AND (col2 = 0))
`

Comment: I tried `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and `"Rows Removed by Filter: 1033804"
"Planning time: 0.127 ms"
"Execution time: 477.148 ms"`

Comment: How many rows are in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that I can't use LIKE operator with AND operator at the same
>   time if you want to use the created index.

The index can be used in that case. Here's how with your exact table and exact query, with random well-distributed contents among 100k rows:

```
insert into table1 select 
   (random()*10000)::int,
   (random()*10000)::int,
    md5(random()::text),
    0,0 
    from generate_series(1,100000);

ANALYZE table1;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
FROM table1
WHERE col1='somevalue' AND col2=0 AND col3 LIKE '01330021123003003%';
```

Result:

```
 Index Scan using table1_pkey on table1  (cost=0.00..8.32 rows=1 width=59) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((col1 = 'somevalue'::bpchar) AND (col2 = 0))
   Filter: ((col3)::text ~~ '01330021123003003%'::text)
 Total runtime: 0.050 ms
(4 rows)
```

That **`Index Scan using table1_pkey`** shows that the index gets used for that query.

If it doesn't with your dataset, the most plausible reason is that you're searching for values that are too common.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you use pattern matching expressions to no text column. It is better to make col3 as text.

Second think is the way of creating index. To use index with pattern matching expressions you have to create index in special way. See:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-opclass.html

Here you have an example:

```
--Firstly, I generate example data (10m records):
drop table tmp_example_record;
create table tmp_example_record as
select
id,
  floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||
    floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||
    floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||
    floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text||floor(random()*4)::text as quad_tree_path
from generate_series(1,10000000) id;


--Create copy of quad_tree_path -> on this column we create right index type to pattern matching
alter table tmp_example_record add column quad_tree_path_copy text;
update tmp_example_record set quad_tree_path_copy =quad_tree_path;  
--create index, with a special operator class
CREATE INDEX tmp_example_record_quad_tree_path_copy_index ON   tmp_example_record (quad_tree_path_copy varchar_pattern_ops);


explain analize
select * from tmp_example_record where quad_tree_path_copy like '212013223122333%'
--about 10ms
/*
"Index Scan using tmp_example_record_quad_tree_path_copy_index on tmp_example_record  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1000 width=86)"
 "  Index Cond: ((quad_tree_path_copy ~>=~ '212013223122333'::text) AND (quad_tree_path_copy ~<~ '212013223122334'::text))"
 "  Filter: (quad_tree_path_copy ~~ '212013223122333%'::text)"
 */

explain analize
select * from tmp_example_record where quad_tree_path like '212013223122333%'
--more then  2000ms
```